# Symfony profiler url to last request

Tags: symfony, profiling

Is there any url like

http://mysymfony.app/_profiler/LAST_ID?panel=db ???

Have no Symfony Profile Footer when profile a json API and it cost time to go back to the overview everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this that I'm aware of. I checked [the bundle](https://github.com/symfony/web-profiler-bundle) and there's [no route](https://github.com/symfony/web-profiler-bundle/blob/master/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml) that seems to cover this.

It seems plausible to me, however, that you could write you own route and action for it. Start [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html#controllers) and then I think the basic logic of your action would look like this

```
$token = array_pop($this->profiler->find(null, null, 1, null, null, null));
return new RedirectResponse(
    $this->generator->generate(
        '_profiler', 
        array('token' => $token, 'panel' => 'db')
    ), 
    302, 
    array('Content-Type' => 'text/html')
);
```

Comment: Your example did a good work for me I did just an internal redirect so I could use browser refresh to get always the latest. Just to mention it here since symfony 2.8(?) the profiler added a `latest` route: `/_profiler/latest?panel=db`

Answer (score 2):

There should be a response header called: "X-Debug-Token-Link" which is a direct link to the latest profiler. You can inspect that in google chrome devtools after each request.

Comment: Since symfony 2.8 there is a route called /_profiler/latest which will show you the last profile. so no longer need to open the profiler overview or get the correct token.

Comment: But think for someone using curl or something or want to access it programmatically this could be useful. Maybe followingis also interesting: https://symfony.com/doc/current/profiler/profiling_data.html